Laravel- Custom CSS and Bootstrap
I have a blade file in which there is a table which is getting values from the controller executing the stored procedure.
The issue is on my blade file when I use
<!-- Pagination Links -->
   <div class="text-center mt-4">
       {{ $results->links() }}
   </div> 

It takes the laravel pagination as well and the bootstrap as well which breaks my UI, how do I correct this? 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119390/23407188 This worked and is a reference to another question.

Write down the version of Laravel and which CSS you are using.
The default pagination theme is tailwind, so to use bootstrap you need to configure it in AppServiceProvider.
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
 
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 */
public function boot(): void
{
    // bootstrap5
    Paginator::useBootstrapFive();

}

Select one according to the CSS you are using.
    // bootstrap4
    Paginator::useBootstrapFour();
    // useBootstrap() is same as bootstrap4
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
    // bootstrap3
    Paginator::useBootstrapThree();

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view
